# HTML drag & drop feature

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, draggable, drag

i am working on 'create online survey application' like : http://fluidsurveys.com/, in which i wish to give user a drag and drop feature.

what user specifically does is he drags a couple of button (one at a time) and drop it in another container. The problem i am facing is, i want a specific HTML to be dropped on dropable container on every button he drags.

have found many drag & drop examples but all of them drags the item & drop it in another one with same HTML. i wish to drop different html on a perticular button drag.

tried my best to explain the situation, any help with code example will highly appreciable thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using JQuery UI to handle this kind of requirement.

In JQuery UI, you may refer to "clone" helper of Draggable Widget to create an object when your button is dragged, also your can attach a function to draggable event handler to create an object with any desired behavior.

Check following codes:

```
$("#div_dragIcon").draggable({  
    helper : "clone"  
});
```

Here you may define a clonable element to be dragged.

And this:

```
 $("#divCanvas").droppable({  
    drop: function (ev, ui){  
        $(this).append(ui.helper.clone());  
    }  
 });
```

To define a container to accept the dropped object and insert it into the document.

I also have a blog post to this issue, you may check it at:

[JQuery UI Drag/Drop Tutorial with a running example](http://zlnick79.blogspot.com/2014/07/introduction-jquery-ui-dragdrop.html)